# I can't use "friends locations" with the Graph api explorer anymore

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

as the title says, I can no longer use friends locations with the graph api explorer any more(in https://developers.facebook.com). Even if I click all access token checkboxes,(trying to get me/friends?fields=locations.fields(place)) I still get error(
{
  "error": "Request failed"
}). But me/locations?fields=place works, so it must be someting with "friends" that makes it to crash.
I was able use it 2 weeks ago, and I have not done any changes, it just suddenly stoped working. if I login with my test Account I can get all the parameters I request, but not on my primary account. Is there any one that has any idea what the problem can be? or why it occurred? I have done everything that I can think of, from using diffrent web browers, deleting all history, use diffrent computer. I have compared the settings for both my test account and my main account, both have the same settings.

I am sincerely sorry if i have misspelled anything.

Comment: Your title "I can't use the Graph api explorer anymore" is misleading,  this title illustrate that entire Graph API Explorer tool is down.

Answer (score 0):

It happens for me as well for any of the locations methods, but the location method with out the **s** works. I don't know if that data is usable for you.

```
me/friends?fields=location,hometown
```

Comment: location without (s) works but i want to use locaions. it has worked and i want to to continue to work. As i wrote earlier it just stoped working, from working.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the reason to this problem. I has to do with requests from facebook's api, if i lower the Limit per request it works. Then to save the information I use offset.